# How to convert Angular 2 Web app to apache cordova application

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an Angular 2 based web application, now I would like to convert it into a hybrid mobile app using Apache Cordova (Not **IONIC** app). I have to install a few plugins.

I have been looking online but I haven't found anything useful. Please share any useful links or suggestions on this.

Comment: You can use http://www.cocoon.io, it's a great website, it lets you manage plugins, app icons, splash screens and settings with a simple UI. Just upload the index.html, the js and css zipped (your whole project) and there you go!

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do not choose Ionic ?